# MeanJS Not Sending Any Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, meanjs

I've just run into a weird bug with my MeanJS based application.

When I launch the server now with either:

`node server.js`, or `node --debug server.js` via my grunt file, 
the server starts up as it always has and displays request URL's.

I get the following:

```
    Running "env:dev" (env) task

    Running "mkdir:upload" task

    Running "copy:localConfig" (copy) task


    Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
        Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
        [nodemon] 1.9.1
        [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
        [nodemon] watching: gruntfile.js modules/*/server/views/*.html server.js config/**/*.js modules/*/server/**/*.js modules/*/server/config/*.js
        [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
        debugger listening on port 5858


        Running "watch" task
        Waiting...
        --
        MyApplication - Development Environment

        Environment:     development
        Server:          http://0.0.0.0:3000
        Database:        mongodb://localhost/myapplication-development
        App version:     2.0.1-beta
        MEAN.JS version: 0.5.0-beta
        --
        GET / - - ms - -
        GET / - - ms - -
        GET /test - - ms - -
        GET /test - - ms - -
        GET /foo - - ms - -
```

When I go to /test or /foo, it shows up on the console. But the browser never receives any content.

This is just in one particular environment. An Ubuntu 14.04 VM,

On my local development environments (Windows 10 and Windows 7, the application works fine)

I haven't been able to find a cause for this, or any errors that are helpful in determining why content never gets sent.

If I try and use links: `links http://0.0.0.0/foo` for example, I get times back:

```
        GET / 200 49.734 ms - -
        GET /foo 200 14.319 ms - -
        GET /bar 200 9.167 ms - -
```

But no content gets received in `links`.

Any ideas on how to further investigate the cause of this on some environments?

Comment: It's a long shot but maybe different node.js versions?

Comment: From meanjs github page: `Node v5 IS NOT SUPPORTED AT THIS TIME!`. Maybe you're using one version in ur windows env and another one in ubuntu